# Mysql custom function

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sqlyog

Can someone explain why this isn't working? I've tried it in phpMyAdmin and an amended version in SQLYog

```
CREATE FUNCTION `manageDate`(a VARCHAR(200),b DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
DECLARE datevar DATETIME;
IF (a REGEXP '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}') THEN 
SET datevar = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),-8,8),'%d/%c/%y');
ELSE 
SET datevar = DATE_FORMAT(b,'%Y-%c-%d');
END IF;
RETURN datevar;
END
```

Thanks

Antony

Comment: Does it give you any error message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only assigning `datevar` the DATE part of DATETIME.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `manageDate`(a VARCHAR(200),b DATETIME) RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
DECLARE datevar DATETIME;
IF (a REGEXP '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}') THEN 
SET datevar = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(TRIM(a),-8,8),'%d/%c/%y');
ELSE 
SET datevar = DATE_FORMAT(b,'%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s');
END IF;
RETURN datevar;
END
```